# How to make 5:00 pm up to 9:00 pm as an overtime in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime

How can I set a "overtime" value if the time is (5:00 pm up to 9:00 pm) in PHP?

This is my query:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM time");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$time = $row['time'];
```

Comment: why not do it in the query? there'd be less code also

Comment: are you storing time as text? if so, you should rethink this if you're still in the early stages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this with [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php),

```
$current_time = "5:59 pm";
$overtime_start = "5:00 pm";
$overtime_end = "9:00 pm";
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $current_time);
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $overtime_start);
$date3 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $overtime_end);
if ($date1 >= $date2 && $date1 <= $date3)
{
   echo 'Overtime';
}else{
   echo 'Not Overtime';   
}
```